# Cosmos dB is blocking the request to upsert even though its have required RBAC roles

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rbac

I have an azure function to read and update the cosmos document . I enabled the identity and assigned the following roles to azure function identity(service principal). Somehow I'm seeing the following exception. Could you please let me know the build in RBAC roles i should have to assign.

1. **DocumentDB Account Contributor**
2. **Cosmos DB Account Reader Role**
3. **Contributor**

**Exception Details:**

Request is blocked because principal does not have required RBAC permissions to perform action [Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/readMetadata] on resource .

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure RBAC for the data plane not the management plane:

- [Configure role-based access control with Azure Active Directory for your Azure Cosmos DB account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac)

There are two built-on roles but you could also create custom roles:

- Cosmos DB Built-in Data Reader (Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)
- Cosmos DB Built-in Data Contributor (Id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002)

You can use Az Powershell, Az CLI, or the ARM API to [create role asisgnment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac#role-assignments).

AzCLI  sample:

```
$resourceGroupName="<myResourceGroup>"
$accountName="<myCosmosAccount>"
$dataContributorRoleId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"
$principalId="<aadPrincipalId>" # Often called Object ID
az cosmosdb sql role assignment create `
  --account-name $accountName `
  --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
  --scope "/" `
  --principal-id $principalId `
  --role-definition-id $dataContributorRoleId
```

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers. They're not considered valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Somehow I'm seeing the following exception. Could you please let me know the build in RBAC roles i should have to assign

> 1. **DocumentDB Account Contributor**
> 2. **Cosmos DB Account Reader Role**
> 3. **Contributor**

To read and update the `Cosmos DB Account` using Azure Function identity `(service principal)`, it may require the `DocumentDB Account Contributor role`. With this role, you can perform the following actions

```
 Ex:
    Read database account
    Update database account
```

[image]

When I attempt to update a `Cosmos DB Account` using a `Service Principal` with the **Cosmos DB Account Reader** Role, I encounter the following error.

```html
Update-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName <RG-NAMe> -Name <Account-Name> -DefaultConsistencyLevel "Strong" -EnableAutomaticFailover 1 -EnableMultipleWriteLocations 1 -EnableVirtualNetwork 1
```

[image]

To resolve the issue, kindly assign the **DocumentDB Account Contributor** role to perform `read` and `update` operations in the `Cosmos DB account`.

I'm able to update the `Cosmos DB Account` after assigning the role.

If you still encounter the same error, make sure to assign the role to the correct service principal `(Azure Function system identity)`

Refer the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-setup-rbac) for Azure Cosmos DB account

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)